# "ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input" when trying to create Functional API model with Keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-datasets

This is the error I get:

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset'>", "<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TakeDataset'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>

I think this is due to what I'm passing in the model.fit method as the validation and training datasets.

Im trying to create a multi-input model that uses images and metadata stored in a table, where each row contains metadata about that image.

When I train the models separately they work fine with the given training and validation datasets, so I am confused why it is not working now. Im not sure if maybe I have to split and create the datasets in a different way since I am now using the functional API.

```
'''
FOR CNN AND IMAGES
'''

cnn_data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory("training_data")

cnn_data = cnn_data.map(lambda x, y: (x/255, y))

scaled_iterator = cnn_data.as_numpy_iterator()
batch = scaled_iterator.next()
#batch[0].max() #should be 1.0

cnn_train_size = int(len(cnn_data) * 0.8)
cnn_val_size = int(len(cnn_data) * 0.2)+1

#establishes the training and validation sets
cnn_train = cnn_data.take(cnn_train_size)
cnn_val = cnn_data.skip(cnn_train_size).take(cnn_val_size)

'''
FOR METADATA
'''

dataframe = pd.read_csv('MetaDatav2.csv')

# Drop unused features.
dataframe = dataframe.drop(columns=['patient_id', 'lesion_id', 'benign_malignant'])

#remove all rows with missing data
dataframe = dataframe.dropna()

#split the data into train and validation sets, 80/20 split
meta_train, meta_val = np.split(dataframe.sample(frac=1), [int(0.8*len(dataframe))])


#creates a dataset from the df
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):

  df = dataframe.copy()
  labels = df.pop('target')

  df = {key: value[:,tf.newaxis] for key, value in dataframe.items()}

  #returns a dataset object
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(df), labels))

  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  ds = ds.prefetch(batch_size)

  return ds

meta_train_ds = df_to_dataset(meta_train, batch_size=batch_size)
meta_val_ds = df_to_dataset(meta_val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

#training the model
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit( x=[ cnn_train, meta_train_ds ], validation_data=([ cnn_val, meta_val_ds ]), epochs=10, batch_size=100)
```

let me know if you need me to post more code but I think this should be enough